# Remove all elements in string array Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to remove all of strings that match occurrences in the array of 'interestedStudents' in a Mongoose schema.

My Mongoose schema looks like this:

```
// Create a schema.
const schema = new mongoose.Schema<Post>({
    interestedStudents: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            unique: true
        }],
        required: false,
    },
})

//Create model
export const PostModel = model<Post>('Post', schema);
```

I'm trying to remove by using:

```
await PostModel.updateMany({ interestedStudents: { $pullAll : [userId]}})
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> "CastError: Cast to [string] failed for value "[ { '$pullAll': [ '62854109cf9a6db1fcf0393b' ] } ]" (type string) at path "interestedStudents.0" because of "CastError"\n    at model.Query.exec

What am I doing wrong? Is my Schema set up wrong? Maybe it's not an array of string?

Answer (score 0):

It was as easy as this for anyone else coming here:

```
const { modifiedCount } = await PostModel.updateMany({}, { $pull: { interestedStudents: userId } })
```